# QT for Android uses camera causes W GLConsumer: bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x502

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, qml, android-camera

My device is redmi note4 with Android 6.0 and my IDE is Qt 5.8. I use QZxing to implement decoding QRcode. But when I call the camera to scan, I get this log.
And it is strange that it works in another phone(redmi2 with Android 5.1).Someone can give me a hand?

```
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 16
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
D MALI    : gles_state_set_error_internal:75: [MALI] GLES ctx: 0xd9fc0008, error code:0x502
D MALI    : gles_state_set_error_internal:76: [MALI] GLES error info: <type> is GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5 and <format> is not GL_RGB (or) <type> is GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1 and <format> is not GL_RGBA
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
W GLConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-16419-0] bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x502
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 16
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 16
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
V CameraFramework: set Key = focus-areas, value = (0,0,0,0,0)
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 16
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 16
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
I CameraFramework: handleMessage: 4096
I CameraFramework: CAMERA_MSG_META_DATA
```

I call the decode QML page by this button

```
IconButton {
    id: sq_codeIconButton
    anchors.topMargin: 28
    anchors.top: parent.top

    iconSource: "images/ScanQR_Code.png"
    rippleColor: "#FF7F00"
    onClicked: {
        qrCodeReader.active = true;
        rectangle.visible = false;
        console.log("调用摄像头扫描二维码")
    }
}
```

the rectangle is the current page id. qrCodeReader is defined like this:

```
JQQRCodeReader {
    id: qrCodeReader
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    onTagFound: {
        patientNumText.text = "id:" + tag;
        rectangle.visible = true;
    }
}
```

I use the lib through this:
https://github.com/188080501/JQQRCode

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note that it may be better to create a bug report for it.